# Laravel: how to prevent values like created_at user_id_created from sending to frontend

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to stop some data that is being send from backend to frontend. I don't want those fields: `created_at`, `updated_at`, `user_id_created`, `user_id_updated` to be sent from backend to frontend, because it is just waste of time.

I am trying to use this function `mapForTransfer` to unset some values from the table. Not sure though if I'm getting the table key in correct way.

```
public function mapForTransfer($collection) {
    return $collection->map(function($item, $key) {
        $key['id'] = $key[$this->service->getKey()];
        $item['id'] = $item[$this->service->getIdName()];
        unset($item['created_at']);
        unset($item['user_id_created']);
        unset($item['updated_at']);
        unset($item['user_id_updated']);
        return $item;
    });
}
```

Data on frontend without fields:
`created_at`, `updated_at`, `user_id_created`, `user_id_updated`

Comment: What kind of "transfer" are you refering to? What do you mean by "send from backend to front end"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using models and Eloquent, you can simply specify which items to exclude in your model by asssigning them in the protected `$hidden` property:

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent {
    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at', ...];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need that data at all, you could just select what you need in the query `Stuff::where('user_id', 1)->select( 'name' )->get()`, this will only return `name` from that query.

If you need to use `user_id` before sending off the data you can map and collect the desired fields:

`$stuff = $stuff->map( function ($thing) {
    return $thing->only( ['name'] );
});`